# How to transition to another view after FBLoginView is executed in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using Facebook SDK 3.8 in my app.

I am using the FBLoginView graphically to login Facebook user.

I have a few views in my app:

- ViewController (the main view when the app is launched)
- LoginViewController (the view with the FBLoginView)
- StoryViewController (the view that only allows authenticated Facebook user to access)

On ViewController, user click on View Story button and I use segue to direct user to LoginViewController if he is not yet sign in with Facebook.

On LoginViewController, user clicks on the Log in with Facebook, then the app prompts user for some permissions I set, and after user clicks Ok, it just returns back to the LoginViewController.

My question is:
How to transition over to the StoryViewController once user has accepted the permission and logged in to Facebook, in Storyboard mode?

I have the method (below) inside my LoginViewController.m but it is never called.
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView

What I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

I have this inside my AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
    sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {
   // attempt to extract a token from the url
   return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
   //return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication];
 }
```

and I have this inside my ViewController.m

```
 - (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
     NSLog(@"To get FB user profile...");
 }
```

But from the debugger, I didn't get the message "To get FB user profile..."

Answer (score 1):

//Are you implementing this method in AppDelegate ? If not implement it.

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
      sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
     annotation:(id)annotation {
// FBSample logic
// We need to handle URLs by passing them to FBSession in order for SSO authentication
// to work.
return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
```

}

//And u can push your view controller i.e. StoryViewController in this delegate method of fbloginview

```
    - (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
      //you can navigate to your view controller 
     }
```